# mv to file with

Tags: shell, find, osx, mv

I ran the following *mv* command, apparently by mistake using backslashes by mistake instead of slashes.

```
mv 2015-02-02_flyer_ppces.pdf ..\PPCES2015\2015-02-02_flyer_ppces.pdf
```

The output is empty.

The file ..\PPCES2015\2015-02-02_flyer_ppces.pdf is not found by *find* from root. What does actually happen when I do *mv* with such parameters? Does the file with this name really exist?

I use OS X 10.10.2

Comment: While being in the directory where you invoked th command type `ls -a`, you should find a file `..PPCE.....pdf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see file with name `..PPCES20152015-02-02_flyer_ppces.pdf` in the directory where the original file `2015-02-02_flyer_ppces.pdf` was.

Backslash char (`'\'`) is escaping character which you use to escape characters with special meaning for bash like `\, ", ', #, $, <space>` and others.  If you use it before regular character like digit or letter it is the same as writing just that digit or letter, i.e. `\P` is same as `P`.